# pycharm does not show code suggestions or color python code

Tags: pycharm

I have freshly installed Pycharm community edition and the editor does not show me any code suggestions when I write code. It also does not color my python code. I have tried changing the theme but nothing works. Am I missing something?

Comment: Does the file you're viewing have a `.py` extension? Is Pycharm still doing its indexing (it will show a progress bar along the bottom).

Comment: Yes it has a .py extension. I tried the trial version of pycharm pro and it works fine. I wonder if the community edition does not have the code suggestion and color features?

Comment: The community edition does has syntax highlighting

Comment: I only use the Community Edition, and it works fine. Try `File -> Invalidate Cache / Restart`. That tends to fix a lot of odd issues.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions. I am using the trial version for now. Could not get the community edition to work.